# On global solutions of a semilinear elliptic PDE

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Consider the semilinear elliptic PDE
$$-\Delta \phi + \phi +\phi^3=f$$
for a real-valued function $\phi$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $f$ is a fixed $C^2$ function. What is known about the existence and uniqueness of global (that is, defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$) solutions (classical or weak) of this equation?

Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your PDE looks similar to the Allen--Cahn equation, which would be $-\Delta \phi + \phi^3 - \phi = 0$. The similarity could be superficial, and your equation much simpler. If this is not the case, it will be basically impossible to answer your question in this level of generality.

Comment: @LeoMoos different sign. Here the monotone op is $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla \phi|^2+ \phi^4 + \phi^2 - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  f \phi$$ No problem at all, everything peachy in $H^1$ and then in $C^2$ by bootstrap.

Comment: @username, could you please give me a reference for the solution method that you have sketched?

Comment: You can read the lecture note [here](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/49424/materials) or look at the problem sheets for the monotone operator part. For the regularity by bootstrap, It is just usual elliptic regularity: put everything except the laplacian on the right, and gain regularity by inverting the laplacian (do it several time).

Comment: @username, thanks, but these notes seem to focus on bounded domains only, as usual. I just found a nice reference for $\mathbb{R}^n$: https://www.math.tamu.edu/~comech/lib/berestycki-lions-1.pdf